# Getting the sum of previous number incorrect for the Java Program(Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium

For the website, "http://www.americangolf.co.uk/golf-clubs/fairway-woods", I want to do the below stuff.

1) First I want to take the number alone from each of the "Brand" section.
ie., CobraGolf(14) means I want to take 14 alone.

2) Then want to add all those numbers of the Brand Section.

I am successful in 1st step (ie) I have successfully cropped the number from string. But I am unable to add all of the numbers.

Whenever I run, I get the incorrect sum of all the numbers. Kindly assist.

```
 package com;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


    public class Exercise2 {
        static WebDriver d=null;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            d=new FirefoxDriver();
            d.manage().window().maximize();
            d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            d.get("http://www.americangolf.co.uk/golf-clubs/fairway-woods");
            String str1="//*[@id='secondary']/div[1]/div[3]/div/ul/li[";
            String str2="]/a";

            int i=1;
            int old=0, current, sum=0;
            while(isElementPresent(str1+i+str2)){

                String a1 = d.findElement(By.xpath(str1+i+str2)).getText(); 
                System.out.println(a1); 
                String a2=a1.substring(a1.indexOf("(") + 1, a1.indexOf(")")); 
                System.out.println("Substring is -->"+a2); 
                int new1=Integer.parseInt(a2); 
                System.out.println("New 1-->"+new1); 
//Seems the below 5 lines have problem.
                current=new1+old;
                sum+=current;
                System.out.println("Current Sum is -->"+sum);
                old=new1;
                new1=current;
                d.get("http://www.americangolf.co.uk/golf-clubs/fairway-woods"); 
                i++; 
                System.out.println("***********");
            }

            System.out.println(sum);
        }
            public static boolean isElementPresent(String xpathexp){
                List<WebElement> allelements=d.findElements(By.xpath(xpathexp));
                if(allelements.size()==0)
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with

```
current = new1 + old;
old = new1;
new1 = current;
```

You end up adding the same values several times. Use just

```
int current = Integer.parseInt(a2);
sum += current;
```

For example lets assume first number in `a2` is 1 and the second one is 3

First iteration:

```
new1 --> 1
current = new1 + old; current --> 1 
sum += current;       sum --> 1
old = new1;           old --> 1
new1 = current;       new1 --> 1
```

Second iteration:

```
new1 --> 3
current = new1 + old; current --> 4 
sum += current;       sum --> 5
old = new1;           old --> 3
new1 = current;       new1 --> 4
```

`sum` is 5 instead of 4.

Comment: Yeah you are right. well answered. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you do something more like the below. It will significantly simplify your code.

`brands` contains the `span` tags with class `refinement-count`. The text inside contains the number you are looking for and generally take the form, " (14)". The code then loops through all of those (only under the Brand category), strips out all characters except numbers, and then converts them to an `int` and adds them to the current `count`.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.americangolf.co.uk/golf-clubs/fairway-woods");
    List<WebElement> brands = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.refinement.brand span.refinement-count"));
    int count = 0;
    for (WebElement brand : brands)
    {
        count += Integer.parseInt(brand.getText().replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Comment: Hi JeffC, Nice Code. Just wanted to ask one thing. Can u please explain the replaceAll.? I am new to Java and Selenium so little bit stuck here. what is \\D+ and ""? Also, if possible please explain  List<WebElement> brands = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.refinement.brand span.refinement-count"));
  Thanks.

Comment: It replaces all characters that aren't a digit with empty string... so basically you are left with nothing but the number.